# Why won't Google Map API V3 canvas print when I print a webpage?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webkit, webkit-transform

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide! I created a map tool that seems to work well; I get a map, a draggable route, multiple waypoints, and a complete, dynamic directions_panel. I want users to be able to print this webpage and get the map_canvas and the directions_panel. In testing, the print preview used to include the map_canvas, but somewhere along the way, the map_canvas stopped appearing when I print the webpage. How can I get it to show up when I print?

Here's my HTML.

```
<div id="map-route-page">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="map-buttons">
<input type="submit" id="showform" value="Edit Map">
<a href="javascript:if(window.print)window.print()"><input type="submit" id="printpage" value="Print this Page"></a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="directions_panel"></div>
</div>
```

Update: Messing around with the CSS, I found that the map becomes printable if I remove the "position:relative" and "-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);" from the #map_canvas. Unfortunately, this makes the whole printed page look strange (map is too large and out of position.) Is there another tag or CSS I should add to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Phew! After a ton of trial-and-error, I found a solution. While I had specified the width and height of my #map_canvas in my main.css file, I had not specified these attributes in my print.css file. I did not edit either the position:relative or the -webkit-transform attributes in order to make this work for me.